# monitoring disc reads

Tags: php, include, apc

i want to use apc in php, to avoid disc reads when including files.
But how can i know if files are really coming from shared memory, instead of disc reads?
Does anyone know how to measure the number of disc reads for a php script, or in a time interval?
(on windows server 2003)
Thanks a lot in advance,

regards,

Charles

Answer (score 2):

APC has an info page APC.php which will answer a lot of your questions:
http://www.electrictoolbox.com/apc-php-cache-information/

Using a [Ram Disk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ram_disk) you can force a cache to use RAM instead of a slow disk drive.  Another possible solution is to use Solid State Drives (SSDs) which have much faster read speeds compared to platter drives.   Setting up a RAID0 of fast SSDs would improve cache performance.

Comment: Thanks fort the anwsers!
I am familair with the output of APC.php. But i rather have the number of disc reads from an other source, because that will be more objective. An USB drive would be more objective, but is less usefull for a remote server.
Measuring the number of disc reads (per time interval, or perphp-script) seems a verry basic thing to me. Does anyone knows how to do that (on windows)?
regards,
Charles

Answer (score -1):

> But how can i know if files are really
>   coming from shared memory, instead of
>   disc reads?

One simple solution might be to place the files in a USB drive (*one of those that has a LED light for disk reads / writes so you can see*) and use `sleep()` to make sure and `include()`s / `require()`s.

Comment: by default APC will stat the files, which would probably make the lights flash even though the contents aren't being read